# Simple C++ Code giving wrong answers

Tags: c++

If I input 299,399,10,5 in order, the computer should give me an answer of 5.But it gives me -5. Why not 5? And this confuses me. Help!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    int a=x-y;
    return a;
}

int x(int a)
{
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;
}

int y(int a)
{
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << add(x(a), y(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The compiler is free to call x(a) and y(b) in any order it likes.  If you write this:

```
int c = x(a);
int d = y(b);
std::cout << add(c, d);
```

It should work.

Oh, and please don't name subtraction functions 'add'... :)

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming that compiler working like a human and it would call from left to right inside a function's parameter list.
Now it just does the opposite!
And yes, add() should only do add!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
std::cout << add(x(a), y(b));
```

the order in which `x(a)` and `y(b)` are called is unspecified by the C++ standard.   Which means `x()` might be called before `y()`, or it might not.

You are assuming `x()` is called first.   If `y()` is called first, you will get the results you see.     The compiler is correct either way (that's essentially what "unspecified" means in the standard, in this case).

If the order of such things matter, you need to force the issue by ensuring the right order.   For example;

```
a = x(a);
b = y(b);
std::cout << add(a,b);
```

There are also concerns as `x()` and `y()` do not use the values passed from the caller.   Unless they are a placeholder for something else which the function will need, there is no reason the caller should have to pass them.

And having a function named `add()` that does subtraction .... wash your mouth out with soap.

Comment: Thanks!
I was assuming x() is called first. As I thought the compiler would execute from left to right inside a function's parameter list.
I did a test, it's just the opposite. The compiler execute from right to left!!!
Yeah, add() should do add...

Comment: It is "just the opposite" with your compiler.   Don't write code which relies on that though.   The actual order is implementation defined, which means different implementations are allowed to pick different order.   And other compilers do.

Comment: Thanks for you advice!
"Implementation defined", first time heard this. But now I know I have to tell the compiler the exact order to call functions. Good!!

Comment: I was tired when I typed my reply and that comment - will correct shortly.   The order of evaluation of function arguments is actually unspecified, not implementation defined.    The terms "undefined", "unspecified", "implementation defined" have specific meanings in the C++ standard (and the C standard as well).  It would be a good idea for you to learn what they mean since understanding them will help with understanding several aspects of C/C++.

Comment: Thanks! It's very kind of you to advise me this things! Yeah, I am learning the C++ for several days. Every concept is very new to me, but I find it's very interesting. I am learning a learn C++ tutorial:)
Hope there can be some progress~~

Answer (score 0):

because x = 5 and y = 10, so 5 - 10 = -5

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

In your question first Y(a) function executes and than x(a) function. As C/C++ is a right left executable function. Whenever you mention function inside a function 
example c=(X(a),Y(b));
In this example first your Y(a) function is executed and then your X(a) function. your program is correct but need a clarity over which function is executing. Hence I have updated your code as below.

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
  std::cout<<"Executing add function";
  std::cout<<"x="<<x<<" y="<<y;
  int a=x-y;
  return a;
}

int x(int a)
{
  std::cout<<"Executing X function";
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout <<"X will return "<<a;
  return a;
}


int y(int a)
{
  std::cout<<"Executing Y Function\n";
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout <<"y will return "<<a;
  return a;
}

 int main()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cin >> b;
  std::cout << add(x(a), y(b));
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can easily find out which function is executing and can provide input accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was assuming compiler would execute from left to right inside a function's parameter list.
Now I know it's just the opposite!

Comment: Caution: this answer is wrong.  It is random order.

Comment: You mean that the order is dependent on the kind of compiler?
I did several tests, and every time my compiler called from right to left inside a function's parameter list.